# Webdriver Select a Dropdown Value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Introducing myself:**

2 years ago I discovered my passion for coding. It is so much much fun. I love it!!! It all started with VBA. Then I switched to Python. Currently I am doing a python course and reading a lot. If anybody has a good literature advice. I am happy to get one. :) As you see I am pretty new to this world.

**My Problem**

Basically it will be a web scraper.  I want to got through several sites and collect information. Collecting is working. Not working is go to the next site. I did some simple debugging and read about my issue. However I am not able to solve this problem on my own... I hope you can help me.

On the bottom is a dropdown menu to select the next page. My issue is to select the next site. There are no pathways to go to the next site. I have to select the page in the dropdown. Looks like this:

```
<select name="page" id="page" onchange="getApi('ispagination')">
<option selected="" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

**Try #1**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://cnft.tools/lunars")
time.sleep(2)

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]')
next_site =driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]/option[2]')

print("Element dropdown is visible? " + str(dropdown.is_displayed()))
print("Element next_site is visible? " + str(next_site.is_displayed()))
print(next_site.text)
print(dropdown.text)

drp = Select(dropdown)
drp.select_by_visible_text("2")
```

Output:

```
Element dropdown is visible? True
Element next_site is visible? True
2
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323

Selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: none
```

I have read this error is typical, when the object is not visible. Errorhandling shows it is visible. I can also find the element for site 2.

**Try #2**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("https://cnft.tools/lunars")
time.sleep(2)

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]')
next_site =driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]/option[2]')

print("Element dropdown is visible? " + str(dropdown.is_displayed()))
print("Element next_site is visible? " + str(next_site.is_displayed()))
print(next_site.text)
print(dropdown.text)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(dropdown).click().perform()
```

Output:

```
Element dropdown is visible? True
Element next_site is visible? True
2
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323

selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: None
```

I have read this issue may also occur if the element is not visible. However it is visible?!?

I am looking forward to advices and to learn.

Biotonne

Comment: It does currently work in Chrome so the issue might just be timing for try 1 or the browser type used since some elements might change and the speed.

Comment: code works correctly on Firefox

Comment: I checked Chrome, is working. Any suggestion why safari is making trouble?